# Windows 8.1 clean install keeps failing with Oxc0000005 error

Tags: windows-8, installation, ssd

I'm encountering the error Oxc0000005 when making a clean install of Windows 8.1 x64 on a Samsung 840 SSD.

I don't know where the error is coming from, I'v already tested several solutions/workarounds I found online and nothing seems to work. The SSD is healthy, I can install Linux (Ubuntu) on it, but apparently the Windows install reports the drive as "locked" when trying to "refresh" the install.

According to diskpart, however, the SSD is not in *read-only* mode, so I don't understand what is going on. I had Windows 8 installed before formatting the drive.

Comment: Have you tried to update the firmware on the drive?

Comment: I have not as of late, mainly because Samsung utility is only for Windows, which I don't have atm. I will try it though.

Comment: Here is an ISO link for the SSD firmware: http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/samsungssd/downloads.html

Comment: I seem to be unable to update the SSD's firmware, using Samsung's bootable ISO I get: Firmware Upgrade unsucessful!!! Firmware version mismatch.

Comment: So I assume I can't update the firmware because the drive is somehow locked