# Create UEFI-bootable DVD with Windows 8.1 iso

Tags: boot, installation, windows-8.1, uefi

I'm trying to set up a UEFI-boot of Windows 8.1. However, I seem to be unable to install it with a USB drive ([previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/732015/windows-8-1-clean-install-keeps-failing-with-oxc0000005-error)), and when I try to install with a DVD (the same iso), I don't get the UEFI boot option on startup, contrary to what happens when I use a DVD burned with e.g. an Arch Linux live install.

How exactly could I be able to boot with UEFI my Windows 8.1 iso from a DVD?

Comment: The .iso should already be EFI bootable disk since it has the required drivers

Comment: @Ramhound That's what I though, but the fact is that I can use UEFI to boot into the USB but not into the DVD, which is weird since both are using the same Windows 8.1 iso

Comment: If that's the case the I suspect the method of burning the disk

Comment: You did set the computer to boot from CD/DVD first, right? Does your computer have secure-boot, is it on or off?

Comment: I press F12 to reach the boot options at boot, the motherboard throws a list of the available options. If the DVD/CD allows EFI boot, the option appears. I have Secure Boot disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup **boot-loader** inside your bios settings.

If your computer has enabled **Legacy Support**, **disable** it if you want to have UEFI support.

You would need to setup UEFI **boot order** and setup the DVD as the main source in some cases.

Also try to **disable** **Secure Boot** in your bios settings to successfully install the system in UEFI boot mode.

We need more info about your motherboard or a laptop if you want us to help you with more details.